# Questions about CACM collection

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval, data-retrieval

I'm using CACM document collection. I tried to search more information on this collection online but unfortunately I didn't find what I was looking for. If I've understood correctly, this collection contains documents from a paper journal. As far as this is concerned, I don't understand why every document  always cites itself (see only the links of type 5). I don't understand either why if document *x* cites document *y*, then document *y* cites document *x* (see only the links of type 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Cornell Computer Science Technical Report written at the time the collection was created that describes the collection.  See: http://hdl.handle.net/1813/6401

Ellen Voorhees

NIST